# Time Out when Executing a SQL Query. Any Solution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeout

We use a google script to get data from a SQL database into a spreadsheet. There is a time-driven trigger for the function.

Every time I run the function, there is a time out.

> Exception: The query has timed out

When I run the function a second time, it usually works fine. Does anybody has a solution for that?

The address and password of the Database is not shown here.

````
function onOpen() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var menuItems = [
    {name: 'JTL Import', functionName: 'readData'}
];
spreadsheet.addMenu('JTL-Import', menuItems);
}

// Replace the variables in this block with real values.
var address = 'XXXX'; //ex. '10.1.1.1:1433'
var user = 'TAXDOO';
var userPwd = 'XXX';
var db = 'eazybusiness';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://' + address + ';databaseName=' + db;


function StockUnitsSold30days() {
 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);


 var stmt = conn.createStatement();

 var results = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a.cArtNr SKU, aaI18n.cwertvarchar [Cut_ID], CONVERT(FLOAT, ISNULL(wmsLager.fbestand, 0)) [Stock_WMS], CONVERT(FLOAT, ISNULL(StreckenLager.fbestand, 0)) [Stock_Streckenlager], CONVERT(FLOAT, ISNULL(fba.fanzahlfba, 0)) [Stock_FBA], CONVERT(FLOAT, ISNULL(PendingLager.fbestand, 0)) [Stock_Pending], CONVERT(FLOAT, ISNULL(WmsAusgang.Anzahl, 0)) [Units_WMS_Outgoing], CONVERT(FLOAT, ISNULL(fbaAusgang.SumAnzahl, 0)) [Units_FBA_Outgoing],CONVERT(FLOAT, ISNULL(MengeAufWarenEingang.fAnzahlAktuell,0)) [Stock_Wareneingangsplatz] FROM dbo.tartikel a INNER JOIN dbo.tartikelattribut aa ON aa.kartikel = a.kartikel INNER JOIN dbo.tartikelattributsprache aaI18n ON aaI18n.kartikelattribut = aa.kartikelattribut AND aaI18n.ksprache = 0 INNER JOIN dbo.tattributsprache attributI18n ON attributI18n.kattribut = aa.kattribut AND attributI18n.ksprache = 0 AND attributI18n.cname = 'CutDesign_ID' LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vlagerbestandfba fba ON a.kArtikel = fba.kartikel LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vlagerbestandprolageralle wmsLager ON wmsLAger.kartikel = a.kArtikel AND wmsLager.kwarenlager = 4 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vlagerbestandprolageralle StreckenLager ON StreckenLager.kartikel = a.kArtikel AND Streckenlager.kwarenlager = 5 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vlagerbestandprolageralle PendingLager ON PendingLager.kartikel = a.kArtikel AND PendingLager.kwarenlager = 7 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT a.kArtikel, SUM(wla.fAnzahl) Anzahl FROM   dbo.tBestellung b JOIN dbo.tbestellpos bp ON bp.tBestellung_kBestellung = b.kBestellung JOIN dbo.trechnung r ON r.tBestellung_kBestellung = b.kBestellung JOIN dbo.tLieferschein l ON l.kBestellung = b.kBestellung JOIN dbo.tLieferscheinPos lp ON lp.kBestellPos = bp.kBestellPos JOIN dbo.tWarenLagerAusgang wla ON wla.kLieferscheinPos = lp.kLieferscheinPos JOIN dbo.tArtikel a ON bp.tArtikel_kArtikel = a.kArtikel WHERE  DATEDIFF(dd, b.derstellt, GETDATE()) <= 30 GROUP BY a.kArtikel ) AS WmsAusgang ON WmsAusgang.kArtikel = a.kArtikel LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT map.kArtikel, SUM(abp.nQuantityPurchased) SumAnzahl FROM   dbo.pf_amazon_bestellung ab JOIN dbo.pf_amazon_bestellungpos abp ON abp.kAmazonBestellung = ab.kAmazonBestellung JOIN dbo.tBestellung b ON b.cInetBestellNr = ab.cOrderId JOIN dbo.trechnung r ON r.tBestellung_kBestellung = b.kBestellung JOIN dbo.pf_amazon_angebot_mapping map ON map.cSellerSKU = abp.cArtNr WHERE  nFBA = 1 AND cOrderStatus = 'Shipped' AND DATEDIFF(dd, b.derstellt, GETDATE()) <= 30 GROUP BY map.kArtikel) FbaAusgang ON FbaAusgang.kArtikel = a.kArtikel LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ta.kArtikel, twle.fAnzahlAktuell FROM dbo.tArtikel ta JOIN dbo.tWarenLagerEingang twle ON twle.kArtikel = ta.kArtikel JOIN dbo.tWarenlagerPlatz twlp ON twle.kWarenLagerPlatz = twlp.kWarenLagerPlatz WHERE twlp.cName    = 'Wareneingangsplatz') MengeAufWarenEingang ON MengeAufWarenEingang.kArtikel = a.kArtikel");
 var metaData=results.getMetaData();
 var numCols = metaData.getColumnCount();

 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Test");
 //you can use the following line to get the active sheet
 //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();



 sheet.clearContents();

 var arr=[];

 for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
  arr.push(metaData.getColumnName(col + 1));
 }

 sheet.appendRow(arr);


 while (results.next()) {
  arr=[];

  for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {

   arr.push(results.getString(col + 1));
  }
 sheet.appendRow(arr);

}

results.close();
stmt.close();

sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, numCols+1);


}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Runs slow first time and then fast right after can be a sign of a poorly optimized query.
If there' a table scan, the data might be loaded into cache the first time. It's in cache the second time.

That's a lot of JOINS and a big query.  I would recommend a stored procedure if it's an option. The query plan might indicate missing indexes.  It should also show the most expensive operations.

If 30 days is is a small fraction of the data and derstellt has an index, then compare the column directly to a date.  Wrapping a DATEDIFF around the column prevents effective use of the index on that column.

DECLARE @TodayMinus29DaysMidnight datetime = CAST(GETDATE() - 29 as date)

SELECT...
WHERE b.derstellt < @TodayMinus29DaysMidnight

I would also verify the derived table with the DISINCT.  Would a GROUP BY be better?

Comment: Thanks - I will pass this information to our database specialist. I was wondering if there is a function in google script that can repeat the query till it was fully executed?

Comment: Applying functions to column values preclude efficient index use. Refactor the `WHERE` clause predicate `DATEDIFF(dd, b.derstellt, GETDATE()) <= 30` as `WHERE b.derstellt >= DATEADD(dd, -30, GETDATE())`.